# Can I run mesos/marathon application at specific host?

Tags: mesos, marathon

I wanna use marathon as cluster monitoring and management. Bellow scenario is possible?

My Scenario

- Cassandra 5EA was already deployed and are running.
- Cassandra hosts are physical machine.
- I want to run script that verifies healthness of cassandra each host. ex) cassandra process, disk usage, number of file, ..
- If problem found at host, than run correcting script on that host. Script launched manually.

Each script can be run by marathon application. But I couldn't found run application on (specific) error host.
No restriction of adding machines and installing mesos components.

And if you know more suitable tool, please recommend!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not running Cassandra on Mesos I think Marathon is not the best choice. From your description, it looks like you need a monitoring tool (e.g., [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/projects/nagios-core/)) rather than service Orchestration.

Please extend your question with more information. It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for answer. We are trying jabbix now. Nagios is also possible option.